# Memory allocated by an IO function is not getting freed even after the value has been computed

Tags: haskell, memory, optimization, memory-management, profiling

Suppose we have to execute a number of complicated IO actions that each occupy a lot of space but return a rather simple value, such as Int or String. In real world that may be, for example, https get requests. I will refer to an action of such kind as `hardIO` here.

```
page <- hardIO
```

Naturally, as the program has progressed past this line, we would like to have all the memory `hardIO` had allocated freed, except for the small bit we keep the actual value in. There is no reason to keep large amounts of data that was only required to execute the action and compute the result.

I noticed that it's not in fact the case. Actually, `page` keeps occupying a lot of space until after the last reference to it. For example, if I want to print the result of execution of `hardIO` in the end of the program, no memory will be freed until then. No memory freed at all! In fact, it may even occupy twice as much memory after it was executed than the maximum of what it was occupying in the process of execution.

```
page <- hardIO
-- A lot of memory not getting freed!
print page
```

As we start to fetch linearly many pages, the space will get wasted linearly excessively. I believe the algorithm should run in constant time, except the linearly growing, but still relatively small list of results.

---

I'm trying to write a program that repeatedly gets certain https API endpoints and around about the hundredth request it finishes eating the RAM, starts swapping and I have to kill the process. (Aside: I guess the copying garbage collector doesn't go well with swapping.) This is very frustrating. You may review the actual code [here](https://github.com/kindaro/stat1) (the commit fe0ebcb should more or less work).

In attempts to solve the issue I have put together a simplistic program that showcases the essence of the problem. If we find a solution for the simplistic case, the general solution will surely follow at once. You may review the simplistic program [here](https://github.com/kindaro/io-mem). (I included the script that I use to build it and obtain the profiling results.) The memory profiling graph for `hardIO` cost centre shows us that at the time between the of binding and the release of its return value, a lot of space is being occupied by unlabeled gray stuff. I guess that's what we need to get rid of.

Comment: Have you tried using `evaluate` on the result of each `hardIO`? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate Or just using a bang pattern like  `!a <- hardIO 100000 1`. My initial impression is that computing something in `IO` doesn't automatically mean that the result value is actually in WHNF.

Comment: Include a minimal but complete example in your question, please. You've made some progress in your "simplistic program", but I think it can probably be cut down even more, and should be included here, not hosted elsewhere. [Further details and advice in the official help.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In your simplistic program, try `return $! arrTotal + random` instead.  My guess is that `arrTotal` is a big thunk that isn't being evaluated.  @dandiaz's suggestions are also good.